# OpenDNS IP Conflict

Tags: update, opendns

I have downloaded the OpenDNS client and it was working great till today. Shows me this error:

> dynamic IP update failed with message !yours or "Your IP address is taken by another user."

I am pretty sure i'll get away with the problem by just restarting my connection as i'll be assigned a new dynamic ip. But I wonder how this is happening in the first place. Shouldn't Dynamic IP be unique for everyone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You could be behind a NAT
- Your system could have just renewed it's DHCP address and the previous user had a OpenDNS client running.
- Somehow OpenDNS (server or client) is confused and has managed to see you twice.

I suspect you should just restart the client and then if the issue persists then then check on the OpenDNS site http://www.opendns.com/support/.